Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and $T_1$,$T_2$ be two nilpotent operators on $V$.
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and $T_1$,$T_2$ be two nilpotent operators on $V$.Let $W_1$=$\{v\in V:T_1(v)=0\}$ and $W_2$=$\{v\in V:T_2(v)=0\}$.Which of the following statements are false?

$1$.If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are similar then $W_1$ and $W_2$ are isomorphic vector spaces.$2$.If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are isomorphic vector spaces, then $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the same minimal polynomial.$3$.If $W_1=W_2=V$, then $T_1$ and $T_2$ are similar.$4$.If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are isomorphic vector spaces, then $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

From the given informations $W_1=N(T_1)$ and $W_2=N(T_2)$.Option(1): if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are similar then $\rho (T_1)$=$\rho (T_2)$ $\implies \eta (T_1)=\eta (T_2)$(as both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear operators on finite dimensional vector space $V$)).Thus $dim(W_1)=dim(W_2)$.Since $W_1$ and $W_2$ are finite dimensional vector spaces of same dimension.Hence they are isomorphic.Option(4):If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are isomorphic then $dim(W_1)=dim(W_2).\implies \eta(T_1)=\eta(T_2).$Now as $T_1$ and $T_2$ are nilpotent opertors on same vector space $V$.So zero is the only eigen value of both $T_1$ & $T_2$ and hence  $C_{T_1}(x)=C_{T_2}(x)=x^{dim(V)}$.Question: Is isomorphism of $W_1$ and $W_2$ necessary in order to show $C_{T_1}(x)=C_{T_2}(x)$?Option(3):Since $W_1=W_2=V$ $\implies m_{T_1}(x)=m_{T_2}(x)=x^{dim(V)}$ and $C_{T_1}(x)=C_{T_2}(x)=x^{dim(V)}$(as $0$ is the only eigen value of $T_1$ & $T_2$ and W_1 and W_2 are corresponding eigen spaces) therefore Jordan canonical form of both $T_1$ and $T_2$ is same (precisely jordan block corresponding to eigen value $0$ of size dim(V)).Therefore $T_1$ and $T_2$ are similar.Option(2):As minimal polynomials of $T_1$ and $T_2$ may not be same hence $T_1$ and $T_2$ may not be similar.
Is my reasoning correct?Is there better way to solve this problem?

What are $\rho$ and $\eta$?

@Joppy Rank and nullity respectively.


Looks good. 2. You are correct, but give an example - there should be one for 4x4 matrices. 3. You are correct, but a simpler explanation is that $W_1 = W_2 = V$ implies $T_1 = T_2 = 0$. 4. All nilpotent operators have characteristic polynomial $x^n = 0$ so this is true unconditional on $W_1 \cong W_2$.


@Joppy for (3) your explanation is simple.

@Joppy I think for option (2) my explanation is wrong.I think minimal polynomial must be same in order to maintain geometric multiplicity.

@Joppy Only rearrangement of Jordan blocks will give different JC forms.
